# SharePoint Session Management

Tags: session

I have a SharePoint Forms based authentication website (**Back end - MYSQL**) where I need to add a functionality, so that if one user is logged in from one browser and he tries to login in again another time without logging off the previous session, his previous session should get abandon automatically.

My question is if there is any out of box feature available in SharePoint through which we can manage this thing?  If not then please let me know the approach for this.